# 2D line renderer reflection issue - Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I make a 2d line renderer reflection on a specific object tag, it's working but only on the left side when on the right side the reflection is not showing, I don't have any idea why because when my script is on 3d it's working fine.

this is a script that I convert from 3D and I change it all to 2D.

```cs
    public int reflections;
    public float maxLength;

    private LineRenderer lineRenderer;
    public LayerMask layerMask;
    private Ray2D ray;
    private RaycastHit2D hit;

    private void Awake()
    {
        lineRenderer = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        ray = new Ray2D(transform.position, transform.up);

        lineRenderer.positionCount = 1;
        lineRenderer.SetPosition(0, transform.position);
        float remainingLength = maxLength;

        for (int i = 0; i < reflections; i++)
        {
            hit = Physics2D.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction, remainingLength, layerMask);

            if (hit)
            {
                lineRenderer.positionCount += 1;
                lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, hit.point);
                remainingLength -= Vector2.Distance(ray.origin, hit.point);
                ray = new Ray2D(hit.point, Vector2.Reflect(ray.direction, hit.normal));
                if (hit.collider.tag != "Reflect")
                    break;
            }
            else
            {
                lineRenderer.positionCount += 1;
                lineRenderer.SetPosition(lineRenderer.positionCount - 1, ray.origin + ray.direction * remainingLength);
            }
        }
    }
```

**PREVIEW**

[image]

When going to the right.

[image]

When going to left.

Sometimes it flickers too, I don't have any idea how this happens, I thought it was because order layer I have changed this but nothing happen.

Comment: Code looks fine to me except why use `Vector3.Reflect` instead of `Vector2.Reflect`?   Anyway I would double check the layers of your walls and make sure the right wall has a collider2d.

Comment: @Ruzihm sorry I think its a typo there but what I mean is vector2 already edit that, I already checked the wall and all have the BoxCollider2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In regard to the flickering, this is occuring due to a clipping issue with the collided object and the line itself.

Inside of the condition:

```cs
if (hit)
```

Adjust the code to be the following:

```cs
// Get the reflected vector of the raycast.
Vector2 updatedDirection = Vector2.Reflect(ray.direction, hit.normal);
                    
// Create new Ray object & set origin to be 0.01f away from hitpoint so the line is not colliding with the gameobject collider.
ray = new Ray2D(hit.point + updatedDirection * 0.01f, updatedDirection);
```

You can find out more from these links:

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1602542/line-renderer-flickering-when-updated-in-runtime.html

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1690411/help-with-reflecting-in-2d.html?childToView=1690554#comment-1690554

As for the reason the line is not reflecting on the right wall, this is more than likely due to the gameObjects tag not being set to "Reflect". You are only creating a new reflected line when colliding with an object with that tag. Double check that the right walls gameObject has the tag "Reflect" set in the inspector.